# How to reset session/local storage when user opens a new tab?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

How to reset session/local storage when user opens a new blank page (tab)?

In which place should I do that?

Comment: Only when opening a new tab ? Or do you want it when switching to existing tab too ? Be more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach focus/blur event to window in your root component.

e.g ->

```js
// on opening of a new tab
window.addEventListener("focus", e => {
  console.log("onFocus", e);
  sessionStorage.clear();
  localStorage.clear();
});

// on closing the tab
window.addEventListener("blur", e => {
  console.log("onBlur", e);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to have a look at this [Using visibility API in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751656/using-visibility-api-in-angular) 
Put this in your root Component

Answer (score 1):

You can set the token of the login into the localStorage of the Browser.

```
localStorage.setItem('token', tokenForLogin);
```

In order to get the value of the value of token use :

```
let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
```

At the time of new Tab remove the token

```
localStorage.removeItem('token');
```

then again request for token and set it to the local storage by:

```
 localStorage.setItem('token', tokenForLogin);
```

Comment: Where to appy it?

Comment: Add it where you are checking for the opening of new tab .

Comment: use to detect tab change`document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(){
    document.title = document.hidden; // change tab text for demo
})`

Answer (score 1):

localStorage.clear();

or

sessionStorage.clear();

removes all values in one step